# Pandas: How to efficiently update rows based on previous value?

Tags: pandas, optimization

I have the following code that updates the current row based on the status of the previous row:

```
prev_status = 0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if prev_status in [1, 2] and row[column_a] != 0:
        row[column_b] += row[column_a]
        row[column_c] = 0
        row[column_d] = 0
        row[column_a] = 0
    prev_status = row[status]
    df.loc[idx] = row
```

However this is very slow when running on 1GB of data. What are ways to optimize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['previous_status'] = df['status'].shift(1)
df.loc[df['previous_status'] in [1, 2] & df['column_a'] != 0, 'column_b'] += df['column_a']
df.loc[df['previous_status'] in [1, 2] & df['column_a'] != 0, 'column_c']  = 0
df.loc[df['previous_status'] in [1, 2] & df['column_a'] != 0, 'column_d']  = 0
df.loc[df['previous_status'] in [1, 2] & df['column_a'] != 0, 'column_a']  = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), e.g.

`df["new_column"] = df["column_name"].shift(x)`

This creates a column where the values are the values of another column shifted by `x` number of rows. It makes it much quicker to do vectorwise calculations on a column, rather than applying a function to every row in the DataFrame.